# Cannot convert from string to template C2664

Tags: c++, string, templates, typename

I created `List` (a class with template), its constructor receives a value `T`. I'm trying to set that type of value in a `switch` of a class called `Menu` (also with templates). When I tried to run `Menu.run()` all the switch options work except for string.

The error is

> Error C2664   'List<T>::List(const List<T> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'T'

```
//Class List

template <class T>
class List {
public:
List(T value) {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
        this->value = value;
        this->name = "no name";
    }
protected:
    List* head;
    List* tail;
    T value;
    std::string name;

};
```

```
//Class Menu
template<typename T>
class Menu{
public:
    Menu(int dataType) {
        this->dataType = dataType;
    }

    void run(){
        std::map<std::string, List< T > * > list;               
        List< T >* list1 = new List< T >("Test");
        std::cout << list1->toString() << std::endl;
    }
```

```
int main(){
    int dataType = 1;
    if (dataType == 1) {
        Menu <std::string> c(dataType);
        c.run();        
    }else if (dataType == 2) {
        Menu <int> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }else if (dataType == 3) {
        Menu<double> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }else if (dataType == 4) {
        Menu<char> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `List< T >("Test");` to do when `T` is `int`, `double` or `char`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOvweflow! Please reduce the code to the relevant lines. The complete section "for testing" has no meaning to the observed problem C2664. Also the #includes doesn't help (the files are not available anyway). Further you should expect something what should happen in a template for specific parameters. What do you expect in your case? Please extend your question and never use comments to "clarify" points of a question.

Comment: If I'd like to use int it'll be `List< T >(5);//random number` actually this works, just not for strings @AlanBirtles

Comment: I'm sorry @harper this is my first question, I just expect to actually save the value in the List constructor.

Comment: But your code isn't doing `List< T >(5);//random number` when `T` is `int`, it's doing `List< T >("Test")`

Comment: I expect T to be string since `dataType == 1` that's why I tried `List< T >* list1 = new List< T >("Test");`@AlanBirtles

Comment: @KABU09 But your `run` method has to work whatever the type of `T` is, and it doesn't.

Comment: @KABU09 How can these lines work `Menu <int> c(dataType); c.run();` when the `run` method is trying to add a string (not an int) to the list?

Comment: I made those "if" to select the "right" menu according to "dataType" since `dataType == 1` I expect T to be a string@john

Comment: @KABU09 That makes no sense. The compiler doesn't know which option you are going to pick *in the future*. It has to compile all your code **now**, and it tries to compile `Menu <int> c(dataType); c.run();` and it doesn't work for the reasons I explained.

Comment: @KABU09 I'd like to suggest a fix, but I'm not sure what the code is trying to accomplish. What does `list1` represent?

Comment: Now I understand why it isn't working. I didn't quite know how the compiler works. Do you have any suggestion so the user can "choose" which type of data they want to use? @john

Comment: list1 is one of many lists that are stored in the map so later can be "mixed" together. The users must be able to choose the type of data of those lists. @john

Comment: Well as I said, I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but something like this would at least compile `Menu <std::string> c(dataType); c.run("Test");` and `Menu <int> c(dataType); c.run(123);` and `void run(T value){ List< T >* list1 = new List< T >(value);`

Comment: @KABU09 Templates aren't going to work for that purpose. You can't make template selections based on user input, because all template code is worked out by the compiler before the program runs.

Comment: Thank you. That's not quite what I need but it helps!@john

Comment: I'm kinda aware of that but my professor wants me to use Templates. @john

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `main` function the compiler has to compile all of your code. Even if it will optimise it out later because it can see `dataType == 1` the c++ standard says it must generate the code for all the data types first.

You could fix this by using `if constexpr` so that the compiler only compiles the code that is actually being used:

```
int main(){
    const int dataType = 1;
    if constexpr (dataType == 1) {
        Menu <std::string> c(dataType);
        c.run();        
    }else if (dataType == 2) {
        Menu <int> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }else if (dataType == 3) {
        Menu<double> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }else if (dataType == 4) {
        Menu<char> c(dataType);
        c.run();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It sounds like this isn't actually what you want though. The proper solution is to fix the line which is causing the failure:

```
List< T >* list1 = new List< T >("Test");
```

This is only valid when `T` is `std::string`. If you replace it with something more generic then your code will compile. You could use a default constructed value:

```
List< T >* list1 = new List< T >(T{});
```

Or more likely your assignment requires you to read the value from the console:

```
T value;
while (!(std::cin >> value))
{
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "invalid value\n";
}
List< T >* list1 = new List< T >(value);
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I will try what you suggested. And yes I would require to read the value from console.